# Yu Yureka hangs after being updated to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, micromax-yu-yureka

Yesterday, I updated my device to Lollipop, and now it hangs. I have deleted many apps, transfers the to SD card, though it still hangs.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you dirty flash the ROM? Meaning, did you not clear `/data/` before flashing the ROM.

Dirty flashing can cause severe lag and many unexpected problems. 
Please try formatting data partition and flashing ROM again.